# progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader only works on localhost

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Any idea why this would be?

```
#slide2
{   
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/snow.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

After being deployed to my remote host it fails to stretch.  This is IE 8

Comment: Try to add the complete Path or URL on the **src** param.

Comment: Your a genius!  Thanks!